# How To Make This WinForm? Design

Tags: c#

Id like to know how to get a design like this in the link below?

[image: example form]

What I know, its written in C# WinForms but I don't know how to make this design. Is this a special design pattern?

I have searched for this but did not find anything like that.

Comment: I actually doubt that is WinForms. I'm guessing it's WPF. Regardless of what technology they used, they most likely they used some sort of library such as DevExpress to get all of those UI elements.

Comment: Indeed, the graphs really look like DevExpress controls to me

Comment: Is there any free alternative which I can use? Maybe for commercial purposes?

Comment: Anyone have an free solution?

Comment: Which part do you mean???

Comment: The full GUI. If there is an alternative to make an design in WinForms like in the screenshot above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a datagridView and for the charts, you can use excel dlls.
The chart can be drawn using Pie charts type (doughnut)